# Lenovo G50 wireless with Atheros wifi

Tags: 14.04, networking, wireless, lenovo, atheros

I have a brand new Lenovo G50 and am unable to get the Atheros wireless to go.

I've installed the ideapad-laptop package:

```
add-apt-repository ppa:hanipouspilot/ideapad-laptop
apt-get update
rm /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ideapad.conf
```

I've tried creating a new `/etc/modprobe.d/ath9k.conf` containing `options ath9k nohwcrypt=1`, and no luck.

The output for `lshw -class network` is:

```
  *-network UNCLAIMED
       description: Network controller
       product: Qualcomm Atheros
       vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: 20
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:f0800000-f09fffff
```

and `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` is:

```
01:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros Device [168c:0041] (rev 20)
        Subsystem: Lenovo Device [17aa:3545]
02:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 10)
```

finally, `rfkill list all` is:

```
0: ideapad_wlan: Wireless LAN
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no
1: ideapad_bluetooth: Bluetooth
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no
2: hci0: Bluetooth
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no
```

So it looks like it should be there, but `ifconfig -a` lists nothing of the sort.  I'm missing something, I know it.

Comment: Please see my posts #2 and #4 here: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2282387

Comment: Indeed.  Too bad.  Looks like I'm using a usb wifi nic until this becomes supported.  Thanks for the info.

Comment: possible duplicate of [My wifi Qualcomm Atheros Device \[168c:0041\] (rev 20) doesn't show up and work in Ubuntu14.04.3 on lennovo flex 3 14](http://askubuntu.com/questions/678145/my-wifi-qualcomm-atheros-device-168c0041-rev-20-doesnt-show-up-and-work-in)